# Reading PDF into a blob then sending as an attachment

Tags: pdf, powerbuilder, email-attachments

I am trying to read a PDF into a blob object then do an INSERT into my `oracle database` so that it can be sent off as an attachment.  Now the email portion is working, and it adds an attachment but the attachment is always corrupt and I can't open it.  Below is the code where I create my blob pdf, can someone help me figure out why this isn't creating the proper attachment?

```
ls_pdf_name = ls_pdf_path + "\" + "invnum_" + ls_invoice + ".pdf"  
ls_pdf_filename = "invoice_" + ls_invoice +  ".pdf"
ls_rc = wf_check_pdf_status(ll_invoice_number, ls_sub_type, ll_user_supp_id)
If ls_rc = "Y" Then
    li_fnum = FileOpen(ls_pdf_name, StreamMode!)
    li_bytes = FileRead(li_fnum, bPDF)
    FileClose(li_fnum)
    ll_rc = wf_update_pdf_tables(bPDF, ls_pdf_filename, ls_sub_type, ll_user_supp_id, ll_invoice_number, ls_month, ls_year)
```

**EDIT**

So I took Calvin's advice and switched my insert to the following:

Here is the `INSERT` statement that puts the blob into the table

```
INSERT INTO ATTACH_DOCUMENT
(id, filename, mime_type, date_time_created)
VALUES
(ATTACH_DOCUMENT_SEQ.NEXTVAL, :pdf_filename, 'application/pdf', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

UPDATEblob ATTACH_DOCUMENT
SET data = :pdf
WHERE id = ATTACH_DOCUMENT_SEQ.CURRENTVAL;
```

But when I go to open the PDF email attachment from my email, Adobe opens up with this error - Could not open because it is either not a supported file type or because it has been damaged (for example it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't decoded correctly)

Thanks

Comment: Have you compared the original PDF with the PDF attached to the e-mail? Is simply the end piece of the PDF missing? Or are there differences inbetween? The latter could indicate encoding issues either during database access or in the mail.

Comment: @mkl I can't actually open the pdf once it is placed into the database.  It says its corrupt, thats why I think its an issue with placing it into the database

Comment: Have you looked at the PDF to find out in which way it is corrupt? The kind of corruption might be a hint to the cause of it.

Comment: How do I find that information out?  It doesn't give me any error codes or anything.  Just adobe reader says it cannot open it.

Comment: Please supply a sample of such a corrupted PDF to inspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How big is the PDF file?

You may not be getting all the contents with a simple `FileRead()` - try using `FileReadEx()`

Comment: they can be around 200-300 kb, which is bigger then FileRead() of 32k I believe?  I tried FileReadEx but same issue

Comment: What is `li_bytes` declared as?  Can you show the `wf_update_pdf_tables` function?

Comment: `li_bytes` is an integer and I will post the pdf tables function

Comment: the pdf table does inserts into the appropriate tables.  I can't post without heavily editing

Comment: And you're using INSERTBLOB/UPDATEBLOB in that function?

What about the portion that is attaching it to the email, can you post that, maybe it's a problem writing the file back out.

Comment: hey Calvin, I was just doing a strict INSERT into the db, not using INSERTBLOB, maybe that is the issue.. I will try it out in a bit and report back

Comment: Yeah, give that a try.  You'll have to run your normal insert like you've posted, omitting the blob, and then do an UPDATEBLOB on it.

Comment: so I did the update blob, the file increased in size which it should have, but now its giving me an error that it cant open it due to it being damaged or not a supported file type. (sent as an email attachment and not decoded correctly)

Comment: Can you post the code that writes the file back out and attaches it to the email?

Comment: The code that writes it back out,  wouldnt that be the updateblob statement?   As for attaching the email.. my webservice polls the tables and looks for new emails and sends them out that way.

Comment: Well I feel stupid.  It ended up being an error with my ghostscript instance.  It wasn't creating the PDF properly.  Thank you for all your help Calvin

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to check if the pdf is correctly saved in the database :

- don't remove the pdf file after it is inserted in the db.
- using a sql interpreter calculate the size of the blob column you have inserted the file into and verify that it matches the file size.
  You didn't mention the database you are using, for example in ms sql server you could use the datalength() function to do this. Depending on the database you may check if the pdf is corrupted by calculating its md5 hash.
- if you use a capable query tool (eg TOAD for Oracle)  you could save the blob as a pdf file and verify that is readable.